# Can I use a const char* or std::string variable containing grammar as argument to libfmt?

Tags: c++, format, c++20, fmt

Hopefully this is a silly question. I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fmt/format.h>
#include <string>
int main(){
 double f = 1.23456789;
 std::cout << fmt::format( "Hello {:f} how are you?\n", f ) << "\n";
 return 0;
}
```

And this works as expected --*Hello 1.234568 how are you?*

But if I want to encapsulate the string passed into fmt::format as a variable, I run into a compiler error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fmt/format.h>
#include <string>
int main() {
 double f = 1.23456789;
 const char* m = "Hello {:f} how are you?\n"; //can't be constexpr, generated at run time
 std::cout << fmt::format( m, f ) << "\n";
 return 0;
}
```

However, on MSVC 2022 using `#include <format>`, this works perfectly...

```
#include <iostream>
//#include <fmt/format.h>
#include <format>
#include <string>
int main() {
 double f = 1.23456789;
 const char* m = "Hello {:f} how are you?\n";
 std::cout << std::format( m, f ) << "\n";
 return 0;
}
```

Is this possible using libfmt? It appears libfmt wants a constexpr value passed in whereas msvc's `<format>` evaluates this at runtime. What silly mistake am I making here?

Comment: Why do you think that you need it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since libfmt 8.1, you can wrap the format string in [`fmt::runtime`](https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#_CPPv4I0EN3fmt7runtimeE13basic_runtimeI6char_tI1SEERK1S) to enable runtime formatting:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fmt/format.h>
#include <string>
int main() {
 double f = 1.23456789;
 const char* m = "Hello {:f} how are you?\n"; //can't be constexpr, generated at run time
 std::cout << fmt::format(fmt::runtime(m), f ) << "\n";
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks -- That did the trick!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `fmt::vformat` for run-time string

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fmt/format.h>
#include <string>
int main() {
 double f = 1.23456789;
 const char* m = "Hello {:f} how are you?\n"; //can't be constexpr, generated at run time
 std::cout << fmt::vformat( m, fmt::make_format_args(f)) << "\n";
 return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/o99jr4abe)

> Is this possible using libfmt? It appears libfmt wants a constexpr
> value passed in whereas msvc's  evaluates this at runtime.

[P2216R3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2216r3.html#checks) makes [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format) only accept compile-time format string. If you want to use run-time format string you need to use [`std::vformat`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/vformat). I suspect this is just because MSVC has not implemented P2216R3 yet.